Do the D&D 5e 2024 rules let you choose to fail a saving throw?
The new Path of the World Tree Barbarian subclass has a feature called "Branches of the Tree" which states that, as a reaction, you can teleport a creature within 30' of you to a space within 5' of you. It requires vision of the target and destination and a failed strength save. Can a friendly creature choose to fail this save?
I realize that this question is similar to this question, but I want to see if this has changed in the revised rules (I read a rumor that it might be changing). And, while I know this material is yet to be published, content creators (who have received advanced copies) are now allowed to talk openly about the content, and I want to be prepared as a DM. So please cite your source.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Yes, you can choose to fail a save.
Page 11 of the 2024 Player's Handbook, under Saving Throws, reads

If you don't want to resist the effect, you can choose to fail the save without rolling.


I'm posting this from nearby to Wizards' booth where I got an advance copy at Gen Con a few minutes ago. I'll happily update this answer as I read through the book over the next few days if I find exceptions or edge cases, but the base rules for saving throws do spell this out explicitly.

Can confirm! (I also have access to the 2024 PHB.)
